# How to output the list of files from a directory that has multiple folders?

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to ouput the name of the folder and then the files in each folder,by grouping them.
folder1/folder2 are subfolders to test folder.

folder1 => 
 -test.doc
 -test2.doc
 -test33.doc

folder2 => 
 -test3.doc
 -test4.doc

```
<cfdirectory directory="C:\wwwroot\test" recurse="yes" sort="type asc" type="all" filter="*"  name="myList2">
  <cfoutput query="myList2" group="type" >
    #name#<br>
    <cfoutput>
      #name#<br>
    </cfoutput>
  </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close. Change the cfoutput to group by "directory". Within the nested cfoutput, only display files.

```
<cfoutput query="myList2" group="Directory">
   <strong>#Directory#</strong><br>
   <cfoutput>
      <cfif type eq "file">
         #name#<br>
      </cfif>
   </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```